# How to assign enter as a shortcutKey to a button in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a button in a group widget and i simply want to create a keyboard shortcut(enter) so that the button action gets called and focused.Interestingly what happened is when i press space(on keyboard)the respective button action gets called which doesn't work with enter.Eventually all I'm trying to get is simply press enter so that button action triggers.Any ideas so that i can play-around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Enter key (`SWT.CR`) does *not* invoke the current button, but rather the default button of the `Shell`. You set the default button with

```
shell.setDefaultButton(button);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're searching for is the method **#addKeyListener** of class **Button**. Implement a **KeyListener** and in the **#keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent)** method evaluate *keyEvent* like this: `if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR || e.keyCode == SWT.KEYPAD_CR) { //your code here}`

Comment: here SWT.CR related to enter key??

Comment: SWT.CR stands for _Carriage Return_ and is the enter key.